# Ajax request not working three times and then works

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have got multiple JavaScript ajax requests on my page. Now, on a particular ajax call (triggered by an `onclick` event), I get 3 error messages back to back. On checking for `request.readyState` I found that each time the error comes, it's got ready states as 1, 2 and 3 respectively and then it works (readyState=4 obviously).

Here is the ajax request I am sending to the server:

```
function fetch(parameter){
var myrequest=new ajaxRequest()
myrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (myrequest.readyState==4){    //This property is not equal to "4" for 3 calls
   if (myrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){ 
       // Code to be executed for successful call
       }
   }
else{
    alert("Error in Request. Request State is: " + myrequest.readyState);
}
}

myrequest.open("GET", url, true)
myrequest.send(null)
}
```

On triggering the onclick event, I get errors as:

> Error in Request. Request State is: 1
> Error in Request. Request State is: 2
> Error in Request. Request State is: 3

What can be the problem with the request?

Comment: There is no problem. An Ajax requests goes through various states, that's why you are looking for the fourth one only. At that state, the response was received. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_2_.E2.80.93_Handling_the_server_response. Just remove the `else`.

Comment: @Felix King: Yeah, that's correct,  but I've got other similar requests too that have the exact similar structure(if-else loops) but do not have a parameter passed to them. They do not show such errors, why is just this one behaving like this? Is it due to the onclick event or due to the parameter or any other reason entirely?

Comment: I don't know your other code, so I cannot tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are XMLHTTPRequest (ajax) states where:

1 => loading

2 => loaded

3 => interactive

4 => ready

At 4, the ajax request is deemed complete and the returned data can be accessed.

You should just drop the `else` condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct,  but I've got other similar requests too that have the exact similar structure(if-else loops) but do not have a parameter passed to them. They do not show such errors, why is just this one behaving like this? Is it due to the onclick event or due to the parameter or any other reason entirely?

Comment: Here, read this http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html